# remove or replace only the word after a specific word in column pandas using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to use regex to remove or replace only the word after specific word(s) in a column of strings in a dataframe. This means I don't want the spaces to be replace. Just the word the proceeds the specific word(s)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'STRING': [r"THERE IS NO REASON WHY THIS SHOULDN'T WORK!", r"I AM WITHOUT DOUBT     VERY BAD AT REGEX", r"I CAN'T SOLVE A PROBLEM HAT HAS NO INTRINSIC VALUE"]})
 
df.STRING.str.replace(r'/(?<=NO|WITHOUT)(\s+)\w','', regex=True)  #this doesn't work
```

here's my output:

```
                                              String  \
0        THERE IS NO REASON WHY THIS SHOULDN'T WORK!   
1           I AM WITHOUT DOUBT     VERY BAD AT REGEX   
2        I CAN'T SOLVE A PROBLEM THAT HAS NO INT...   

                                      desired_output  
0              THERE IS NO  WHY THIS SHOULDN'T WORK!  
1                I AM WITHOUT      VERY BAD AT REGEX  
2         I CAN'T SOLVE A PROBLEM THAT HAS NO  VALUE
```

Again, i don't want the spaces between them to be removed. I only want the one word after NO or WITHOUT to be removed/replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your regex, `/(?<=NO|WITHOUT)(\s+)\w`, contains several issues:

- `/` - is a typo, it was probably a regex delimiter that got into the pattern
- `(?<=NO|WITHOUT)` - is a lookbehind pattern where alternatives match strings of different length and Python lookbehinds patterns must be fixed-width
- `\w` - matches a single word char, not one or more. There must be some quantifier after `\w`, `*` (zero or more times) or `+` (one or more occurrences).

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'STRING': [r"THERE IS NO REASON WHY THIS SHOULDN'T WORK!", r"I AM WITHOUT DOUBT     VERY BAD AT REGEX", r"I CAN'T SOLVE A PROBLEM HAT HAS NO INTRINSIC VALUE"]})
pattern = r'\b((?:NO|WITHOUT)\s+)\w+'
df['STRING'] = df['STRING'].str.replace(pattern, r'\1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(df.to_string())
                                      STRING
0      THERE IS NO  WHY THIS SHOULDN'T WORK!
1        I AM WITHOUT      VERY BAD AT REGEX
2  I CAN'T SOLVE A PROBLEM HAT HAS NO  VALUE
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/khEKTP/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `((?:NO|WITHOUT)\s+)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value from the replacement pattern): `NO` or `WITHOUT` and then one or more whitespaces
- `\w+` - one or more word chars (replace with `\S+` if you plan to remove one or more non-whitespace chars, or even `\S+\b` to cut off trailing punctutation).

Comment: You should explain the several errors in the OP's current attempt (including the non fixed width lookbehind problem).

Comment: The OP is not assigning the result of `str.replace` to a LHS.  But I have upvoted anyway.

Comment: thanks so much for the explanation. i had made a lot of mistakes there!